# Sharing private data and methods between classes

Tags: c++, class

I have a bunch of classes for a specific feature. Only one of the classes should be instantiated by user code as the others are "helper" classes. However, these helper classes do expose useful information that is user code consumable.

So I could do with the constructors of the helper classes to only be accessible from the main class.

Likewise, it would be useful to have methods and data accessible only from the appropriate classes, and not from the 'user code'.

Solutions I've thought of so far:

Place all the classes for a feature into a single file and use 'static' to create variables that are local to only that file. This would work as there will only ever be a single instance of the main class and all of the 'helper' classes, but it doesn't seem a "nice" solution.

Have the 'helper classes' friend the main class. This would work also, but also give the main class access to all private data in the helper classes which is not ideal.

Inheritance from a virtual base class: Thinking this is possibly the best solution. Shared data via 'protected', private data stays private and public data is exposed. Not punched any holes in this theory yet. Need to consider performance aspect though as this is an embedded system with a clock speed of 72Mhz.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think considering virtual functions in a embedded system, wanting performance, is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use Composition**.

Inherited classes should only inherit functionality and not inherit state. Protected members/functions will possibly divide the state logic into two units. I would say use composition, and access functionality via public functions.

Regrading that your classes will never be good for the user you never know, so I would say don't restrict yourself.

Comment: So basically have the helper classes in the private section of the main class and then have the main class access them on behalf of the user via public methods?

Comment: yup, that's actually the "correct" design. This way you still have encapsulation, you don't restrict yourself and you don't have redundant coupling.